# How to execute sys.dm_exec_connections on behalf of remote server?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, remote-connections

I am trying to find active connections on multiple remote SQL Servers at once without establishing connection to them via SSMS. Is that possible? If yes, please help.

I want to see those connection information on the SSMS of my local SQL Server.

Comment: Well, if one instance has linked servers to the others, you can say `SELECT * FROM linkedservername.master.sys.dm_exec_connections;`... otherwise, no, you can't magically query servers you haven't connected to

Comment: @AaronBertrand This worked. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create linked servers on your local instance, then you could connect there and reference all the other servers through a four-part name reference, like:

```
LinkedServerName.master.sys.dm_exec_connections
```

You could also look into Central Management Servers / registered server groups; SSMS provides some facilities for running the same batch against multiple servers in sequence.

- [Execute Statements Against Multiple Servers Simultaneously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously)